# Topology and "adding sets" in a TVS

Tags: general-topology

Let $V$ be a symmetric open set in a topological vector space $X$ and $x \in X \backslash C.$ Assume that we have for a closed set $C$.

$x+V+V+V \subset X \backslash C$. Is there an easy argument to see that $(x+V+V) \cap (C+V) = \emptyset$? I mean, sure we could assume that there is an element in the intersection and show that this leads to a contradiction, but is there also a faster argument for this?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: And $C$ is supposed to be ?...

Comment: a closed set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the argument you sketched is the way to go. Suppose $y \in x + V + V$ and $y \in C +V$ for some $y$. So $y = x + v_1 + v_2 = c + v_3$ for some $c \in C$ and $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V$. Then $-v_3 \in V$ as well, using that $V$ is symmetric. So $c = x + v_1 + v_2 + (-v_3)$ which shows that $c \in x + V + V + V$, which contradicts $x + V + V + V \subset X \setminus C$.

Note that this works for any $C$ (not necessarily closed), and any symmetric set $V$.